# ssh config change user for one host

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I would like to connect to each server using the `root` user and to `machin` server using `me` user.

I edit `.ssh/config`

```
 User root
 Host machin
 Hostname machin
 User me
```

When I type

```
 ssh machin
```

I get

```
 root@machin's password:
```

What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `ssh_config` manual page:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more
>   host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the
>   file, and general defaults at the end.

You should change the order of your configuration values, first set the host-specific ones then the general ones:

```
Host machin
Hostname machin
User me
User root
```